# Angular 6 HTTP Get request doesn't work on JSON file

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, get

I'm trying to get information from Flickr public RSS feed. I've turned it into a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "title": "Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:41",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320429435",
    "author": "kevinmaxwell535",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
},
{
    "title": "IMG_20181010_171033",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:48",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320431445",
    "author": "Hetoogappeltje",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
}
]
```

and I use a method that calls it like this:

```
private url: string = '/assets/data/flickr.json';

getImg(): Observable<Feed> {
return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

and this works fine!

the problem is that the original json looks like this:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"feed": {
    "url": "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne",
    "title": "Uploads from everyone",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/",
    "author": "",
    "description": "",
    "image": "https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/buddyicon.gif"
},
"items":[
{
    "title": "Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:41",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320429435",
    "author": "kevinmaxwell535",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
},
{
    "title": "IMG_20181010_171033",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:48",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320431445",
    "author": "Hetoogappeltje",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
}
]
}
```

On this file the http get request doesn't work. Any suggestions as to how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON file isn't valid JSON. The array after the key "feed" has no key.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"feed": {
    "url": "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne",
    "title": "Uploads from everyone",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/",
    "author": "",
    "description": "",
    "image": "https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/buddyicon.gif"
},
[...]  <-- value is missing key
}
```

I don't know what that key should be, I called it "feeds", but if you specify one:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"feed": {
    "url": "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne",
    "title": "Uploads from everyone",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/",
    "author": "",
    "description": "",
    "image": "https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/buddyicon.gif"
},
"feeds": [
{
    "title": "Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:41",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320429435",
    "author": "kevinmaxwell535",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/129127425@N08/\">kevinmaxwell535</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/129127425@N08/44320429435/\" title=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_m.jpg\" width=\"135\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Bakers 10th Oct 2018. Kens corner, caught on a Meps spinner. Caught several Perch too all over.\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1922/44320429435_74fc3858b4_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
},
{
    "title": "IMG_20181010_171033",
    "pubDate": "2018-10-10 19:44:48",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/",
    "guid": "tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/44320431445",
    "author": "Hetoogappeltje",
    "thumbnail": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg",
    "description": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "content": "\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/137717399@N07/\">Hetoogappeltje</a> posted a photo:</p>\n\t\n<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/137717399@N07/44320431445/\" title=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"><img src=\"https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"IMG_20181010_171033\"></a></p>\n",
    "enclosure": {
        "link": "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1939/44320431445_c48588cda3_b.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "categories": []
}
]
}
```

You should at least be able to parse the data correctly. In the future, you can use a linter such as https://jsonlint.com/ to help with these types of issues.

Comment: it is a valid JSON, I just wrote the question wrong, sorry about that... the word before the first square bracket is "items": and it still doesn't work.

Comment: No worries. Are you wanting to use this static file for testing or local development versus hitting the actual URL?